# Why is this cover of "New Adventures in Hi-Fi" missing the word "Hi-Fi"?

Tags: album, artwork

I bought a used copy of R.E.M.'s *New Adventures in Hi-Fi* online. Everything's fine, except on the album cover I noticed the word "Hi-Fi" is missing — it just says *New Adventures in* (see below).

No picture of the album I found online has the same mistake, and I could find no other references to the missing *Hi-Fi*. The word wasn't simply erased either, since the text alignment is actually different. The booklet seems genuine too.

Now of course this isn't a grave issue, but it's one that has me curious. Is this a known misprint, and if so, what's its history? May it have been deliberate?

[image: Album cover with a word missing]
[image: Closeup of the disc itself]

Comment: Check the matrix on the disc, this sounds like it could be an imported bootleg.

Comment: It matches the matrix number mentioned [here](https://www.discogs.com/REM-New-Adventures-In-Hi-Fi/release/2519241), so it seems genuine.

Comment: Does the matrix match this? https://img.discogs.com/wclz3G5Wcz9M1sW5hIaF-WSayCU=/fit-in/600x600/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/R-2519241-1318788792.jpeg.jpg Is it _exactly_ the same?

Comment: Interestingly enough, it doesn't! The writing on the back matches the one on the page I linked to, but the text on the front suggests it's from Mexico instead. I've added another picture up there.

Comment: Well, at least one more person thinks it is a misprint: http://www.ebay.com/itm/R-E-M-NEW-ADVENTURES-IN-HI-FI-MISPRINTED-CD-COVER-SUPER-RARE-COLLECTIBLE-ITEM-/152414959469?hash=item237ca3b76d To me, the matrix seems legit, and could be a rare mexican misprint. In this case, it must have been withdrawn by warner, because otherwise it really should exist on Discogs, which it doesn't. The catalog number as seen by the matrix seems legit too, what is the catalog number on the cover?

Comment: @Magnilex It's CX 46320-2, the same as on the matrix. Thanks for the interesting link by the way - I wonder if it really has the potential to sell for that much.

Comment: @vvye I don't think so. Anyway it's an interesting item. R.E.M. is one of my favourite bands, and I own well over 100 records with them, but I never heard of this one. It would be nice if we could confirm this to be a misprint.

Comment: Maybe you could add it on Discogs, it could be useful for other people.

Comment: I used to own this CD. I bought it when I lived in Mexico. It's a curious misprint.